# anti-forgery error in my mvc app

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a simple MVC4 application with below codes:

Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Administrator",FormMethod.Get))
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.username)

        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.password)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.password)

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

After running the Application and going to this Address: `http://xxx/Administrator/Login`

I got this error:

```
The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: is the browsers cookie disabled?!did you get this error on every browsers?

Comment: I got the error in all browsers

Comment: Still happening? I once solved it by restarting my browser.

Comment: It's not about browsers and cookies @DarthVader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antiforgery token makes sense on POSTs while your request is a GET request.

You should have a `Login` method that just displays the login screen (`HttpGet`) and another method that accepts the posted values (`HttpPost`).

The one that just displays values should **not** take the model as the parameter, rather, it should just create an empty model.

Both methods could render the same view.

Comment: I just created another empty Login method. Also I changed the method to Post and It's working